# How to keep scroll position when inserting new rows in datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables plugin to work with my table.
I want to set JSON object as a datasource for my table and update the content every time when this object is changed.

To initialize my table I use the following code:

```
     var obj = [];

     // if I make start initialization of the object - the row in a table appears.
     //var obj = [{"Name": "name1", "Id": "id1", "Value":"value1"}];

     var table;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            table = $('#example').dataTable({
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "sScrollY": "250px",
            "aaSorting": [],
            "aaData": obj,
            "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "Name" },
            { "mDataProp": "Id" },
            { "mDataProp": "Value" }
        ]
        });
    }
    );
```

To update my JSON object:

```
function updateObject() {
    var response = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        url: myURL,
        success: function (result) {
            obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            //table.fnDraw(); - tried this but it doesn't work
        }
    });
}
```

JSON data which I get from the server:

```
 [{"Name": "name1", "Id": "id1", "Value":"value1"}, 
     {"Name": "name2", "Id": "id2", "Value":"value2"},...]
```

Is it possible to refresh table content after I get new data from the server?

**UPDATE:**

```
table.fnClearTable();
table.fnAddData(obj, false);
table.fnStandingRedraw();
```

After inserting new rows, current page gets lost and current scroll position also. **fnStandingRedraw** method helps to keep page position. But scroll jumps to the first row. Is there any way to calculate current scroll position to make a jump back after updating (http://datatables.net/docs/Scroller/1.0.1/) or some other solution?

Comment: did you find a solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can help you. You should first remove all the data and add the new data again, document is [here](http://datatables.net/api)

```
table.fnClearTable().fnAddData(obj);
```

Comment: I also use fnStandingRedraw() plugin to keep my paging position after update. But I can't keep scroll position. Maybe you know how to handle  this problem ?

Comment: Not really, let me see what the problem is?

Comment: You shouldn't have to remove all the data and insert new data. This isn't a good solution for someone who has large data sets and is trying to append data on scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario.
So eventually I solved this way:

```
function UpdateDatatable(data, $table) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: "../biz/datahandler.ashx",
        data: ({data: data}),
        async: true,
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            /* manage the error */
        },
        success: function (dataget) {
            /* maange the success */
            $table.dataTable({
                ...
            })
    });
}
```